# How to get attribute value out as an integer in xslt?

Tags: xslt

My input XML is like:

```
     <item row="4" column="1" colspan="3">
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_15"/>
     </item>

     <item row="2" column="12">
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_22"/>
     </item>
```

My created a variable as:

```
    <xsl:variable name="span" select=item/@colspan"/>
```

I need to convert $span into xs:integer. How to do that? I wonder what's value for $span in the case there is no @colspan (e.g. in the second item in the sample)? What's the elegant way to set $span? Does XPATH 2.0 help in this case?

Comment: It is not clear in which context you use `<xsl:variable name="span" select=item/@colspan"/>`? If those two `item` elements are siblings inside the same parent element and the `select` expression `item/@colspan` makes any sense then you in the first step select both `item` elements but the second step for the second item does not select anything so the complete variable is a sequence with a single attribute node.

Comment: Please say which version of XSLT you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `$span` is either an attribute node or nothing (an empty node-set/sequence). (It could also be a set of multiple attribute nodes, depending on your input).

Since you mention `xs:integer` I assume you're using 2.0+, since there's no such type in XPath 1.0.

The obvious way of converting the value to an integer is `xs:integer($span)`, but this might not be exactly the conversion you want. It will work provided the attribute exists and has the form of an integer; it will also do something if the attribute value is "3.14" - perhaps this isn't what you want.

If you want the variable to take the default value 1 when `@colspan` is absent, the idiomatic way is `select="xs:integer((item/@colspan, 1)[1])"`